# Meaning of numbers in post commit hook details of commit email

Tags: python, svn, visualsvn-server

I am getting the following commit message but I am trying to figure out two things **0700** and **57**. What is the relation with the commit - any idea?

```
A commit has been made to the IAPAdmin repository
*** Commit Information ***
jambhus
2015-04-03 08:58:50 -0700 (Fri, 03 Apr 2015) 57
Adding new file App_new1.java and deleting file App3.java

*** Changed Files ****

D   trunk/Alpha/src/main/java/jar/App3.java
A   trunk/Alpha/src/main/java/jar/App_new1.java
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output is created by the `svnlook` command, which claims to do the following:

> Print the author, datestamp, log message size, and log message.

- `-0700` should be your timezone. Does [UTC-7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%E2%88%9207:00) sound familiar to you?
- `57` is the size of the log message in bytes

Comment: If I want to know about revision number of the commit then  what need to be done,  any idea ?

Comment: If you have access to the post-commit hook and/or `processCommit.py` (which seems to be in use in your installation), you have access to the revision. It is the second command line argument to both programs. If tyour copy of `processCommit.py` is the same as mine (I don't know how many versions exist), the easiest way would probably be to modify it to add the value of `rev` to the message before mailing it, e.g. by adding this after the initial message assignment: `message  = message + "\nrevision: " + rev`

Comment: So my processCommit.py file will look like this ; ............................................commitMsg = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
message = """A commit has been made to the %s repository
*** Commit Information ***
""" % (repository)

message = message + "\nrevision: " + rev + commitMsg.decode('utf-8') + '\n*** Changed Files ****\n\n' + changed.decode('utf-8')
msg = MIMEText(message)